# Why does volume jump to max when I connect my bluetooth headphones?

Tags: macos, ios, audio, bluetooth, headphones

I know I'm not the only one experiencing this. A quick google search shows others have not found solutions to this either.

Sometimes when I connect my headphones via bluetooth the volume jumps to the max volume. Then when I play music or an audio book, it just blasts my ears. I have no idea how that can possibly be because I never have volume on max, so it's not like it "remembered" my previous settings.

What on earth is causing this and how do I fix it?

This problem is SO irritating, especially since I have very sensitive ears and am averse to loud noises. Please help with this.

Comment: Which sound source is the last one that caused this? Mac? iPad? Other?

Comment: This happens to me too on my Macbook Pro

Comment: @bmike happens when i connect to my iphone usually. Could be my cheap Anker speakers or my sony noise cancelling headphones.